# Implement boolean expression with AOI

Tags: logic-gates, ttl, boolean-algebra

Below is a question in my homework:

[[image: Implement <span class=]\$F(P,Q,R,S,T)=(P+Q)S+(R+T)\bar S\$ using one or more 2x2 AOI." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZBzD.png)

---

Here's my attempt for (a):

> **Step 1:** simplify boolean expression.
>
> \$F(P,Q,R,S,T)\$
>
> \$=(P+Q)S+(R+T)\bar S\$
>
> \$=PS+QS+R\bar S+\bar ST\$
>
> **Step 2:** expand boolean expression so that it fits into the AOI gate logic:
>
> \$F=PS+QS+R\bar S+\bar ST\$
>
> \$=\overline{\overline{(PS+QS)+(R\bar S+\bar ST)}}\$
>
> \$=\overline{(\overline{PS+QS})(\overline{R\bar S+\bar ST})}\$

---

I want to know:

1. Do I continue manipulating the boolean expression, or can I just implement the result from Step 2 with AOI gates?
2. Is this double-negate manipulating method suitable for implementing boolean functions with AOI gates (or maybe even all gates in general)?

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of Step 2 has obvious two 2X2 AOI. One for the left hand side let us call it X and one for right hand side let's call it Y.

\begin{equation}
X = \overline{PS + QS} \; (one AOI22)\\
Y = \overline{R\overline{S} + \overline{S}T} \; (one AOI22)
\end{equation}

Also you can implement the inverter using AOI22 as below:
\begin{equation}
\overline{(S.1 + 0.0)} = \overline{S} \; (one AOI22)
\end{equation}

What you need is 
\begin{equation}
\overline{X} + \overline{Y} 
\end{equation}

which you can perform by one 2x2 AOI gate as:

\begin{equation}
\overline{(X.Y + 0.0)} = \overline{X} + \overline{Y} \; (one AOI22)
\end{equation}

This makes 4 AOI22 for the result of Step 2.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I forgot that an AOI can be used as an inverter as well, which was what got me stuck.